# Extract data from MAS90 ERP system into SQL Server database

Tags: odbc

One of our old ERP systems is in MAS 90. I need to extract the data from this source into a SQL Server database.

Are there any ODBC drivers available to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

MAS 90 ships with an ODBC driver called SOTAMAS90.  Depending on the version of MAS that you have, it may or may not have a 64 bit driver available.  The 32 bit driver can typically be found (on 64 bit systems) in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.

In either the 64 bit or 32 bit version, you will find the DSN you need in the User DSN folder.  When you use this DSN in an ODBC application, whether SSIS, a .net application, or just MS Access, you will need to provide a User ID, Password and Company code.  And those credentials won't save.  You will have to pass them in from your client application whenever you use them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I created a linked server to MAS 90 using SOTAMAS ODBC driver successfully.